# How do I execute SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in python MySQLDB

Tags: python, mysql, database, select

```
cursor.execute("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS user_id FROM...limit 5")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
...
total_rows = cursor.execute("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()") #this doesn't work for some reason.
```

Edit: I tried SELECT FOUND_ROWS() FROM my_table...and the numbers are funky.

Comment: Thanks btw. I did not know of `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS / SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` :D

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work here by fetching the result for the second cursor:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS user_id FROM...limit 5")
rows = cursor.fetchall()

cursor.execute("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")
(total_rows,) = cursor.fetchone()
```